# regular expression to find word after a term and before another term

Tags: javascript, regex

The current url is

```
search/warrington/st-album/title/3
```

I need to get the value after `st-` and nothing after `/`. So in this instance I would want to return `album` only.

I am using the expression below

```
var patt= new RegExp((?=/st-(.*?/)));
return patt.exec(url)[1];
```

this however returns `album/`

Can someone please let me know the correct the expression for after and before in the above instance? I.e. to return just `album` and not `album/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new RegExp((?=/st-(.*?/)));` should throw a syntax error actually.

Anyways, to prevent `/` from appearing in the capture group, move it outside the group (using a regex literal):

```
var patt = /(?=\/st-(.*?)\/)/;
```

I don't see a need for the lookahead and you could use a negated character class instead of lazy quantifiers:

```
var patt = /\/st-([^/]+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slash is in the wrong place:

```
var patt= new RegExp((?=/st-(.*?)/));
return patt.exec(url)[1];
```

You need to move it outside the group so that it isn't included in the matches array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var expr = "search/warrington/st-album/title/3";
var regex = new RegExp( /\/st-(.*?)\// );
return regex.exec(expr)[1];
```

it should work

Comment: There is no point in passing a regex literal to `RegExp`. Either directly use the literal or pass a string to `RegExp`.